# Create dataframe out of multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new dataframe out of 3 original dataframes I have.
3 dataframes have format: `Name|col1|col2`. Names are identical from all dataframes, the differences are values from `col1` and `col2`.

df1:

```
abc  1  2
xyz  3  4
```

df2:

```
abc  5  6
xyz  7  8
```

df3:

```
abc  9  10
xyz  11  12
```

new dataframe should have format:

```
abc(df1,df2)  1  6
abc(df1,df3)  1  10
abc(df2,df3)  5  10
abc(df3,df1)  5  2
abc(df3,df1)  9  2
abc(df3,df2)  9  6
xyz(df1,df2)  3  8
xyz(df1,df3)  3  12
xyz(df2,df1)  7  4
xyz(df2,df3)  7  12
xyz(df3,df1)  11  4
xyz(df3,df2)  11  8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, you may need to add another few steps to get in in the format you need but the logic to make it is all there.

```
df1['key'] = 'df1'
df2['key'] = 'df2'
df3['key'] = 'df3'


(pd.merge(
    pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]), 
    pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]), 
    on  = 0).
query('key_x != key_y').
drop(columns = ['2_x', '1_y']))
```

Assuming your current df columns are called 0 to 2

This will get you:

```
      0  1_x key_x  2_y key_y
1   abc    1   df1    6   df2
2   abc    1   df1   10   df3
3   abc    5   df2    2   df1
5   abc    5   df2   10   df3
6   abc    9   df3    2   df1
7   abc    9   df3    6   df2
10  xyz    3   df1    8   df2
11  xyz    3   df1   12   df3
12  xyz    7   df2    4   df1
14  xyz    7   df2   12   df3
15  xyz   11   df3    4   df1
16  xyz   11   df3    8   df2
```

Comment: By the way, in order to get the `x(y,x)`-style output that you wanted in your question, you can do add this line: `df.insert(0, 'my_col', df['0'] + '(' + df['key_x'] + ',' + df['key_y'] + ')')` and then this one: `df.drop(['key_x', 'key_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)`